# Can't run apt-get upgrade ubuntu 14.04 gnome

Tags: apt, gnome, upgrade, package-management

I am currently using ubuntu 14.04 with gnome shell 3.10.4(I downgraded from gnome 3.12) but ran in a problem:
I can't install anything!
If I do

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I get the following

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: The package gnome-accessibility-themes needs to be reinstalled, but can't find an archive for it.
```

If I try to run :

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-accessibility-themes
```

The same error pops out

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: The package gnome-accessibility-themes needs to be reinstalled, but can't find an archive for it.
```

then I ran :

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-accessibility-themes
```

but still the same error came!
Even Aptitude doesn't help.
How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: what is the result of running `sudo apt-get download gnome-accessibility-themes`?

Comment: E: Can't find a source to download version '3.12.0-1ubuntu1~trusty1' of 'gnome-accessibility-themes:amd64'

Comment: manualy download it from here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/gnome-accessibility-themes/3.10.0-1ubuntu2 and install using `sudo dpkg -i package-name.deb`

Comment: repostedas answer then )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

manualy download it from here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/gnome-accessibility-themes/3.10.0-1ubuntu2 and install using `sudo dpkg -i package-name.deb`